# AngularJS 1.x custom filter can't be injected, unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to create a custom filter, but when I try to inject it into my controller, I get an 'Unknown provider' error. I have checked and double checked all the references, but I can't see what's wrong.

I know that the file is referenced in my index.html correctly, it is loaded and can be found by the inspector. This is the code I have:

In my app.js:

```
angular.module('equiclass', ['equiclass.controllers',
                         'equiclass.services',
                         'ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/courses', {
    templateUrl: 'views/courses.html',
    controller: 'CourseCtrl'
  // And some other stuff with routes
});

angular.module('equiclass.controllers', ['equiclass.services', 'equiclass.filters']);
angular.module('equiclass.services', []);
angular.module('equiclass.filters', []);
```

My filter:

```
angular.module('equiclass.filters')
  .filter('testFilter', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return undefined;
    };
});
```

And the controller:

```
angular.module('equiclass.controllers')
  .controller('CourseCtrl', function ($scope, testFilter) {

  });
```

Of course this is quite simplified, but it just doesn't work, and I can't see why. I have made several services and they all work and play along nicely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to inject the filter itself.

This code...

```
angular.module('equiclass.controllers')
  .controller('CourseCtrl', function ($scope, testFilter) {

  });
```

Should be

```
angular.module('equiclass.controllers')
  .controller('CourseCtrl', function ($scope) {

  });
```

And inside `CourseCtrl` you should use your filter as you normally do.

Injecting the module `'equiclass.filters'` into your module `'equiclass.controllers'` is enough.

I had a similar issue and made a post about it [on my blog](http://www.seangwright.me/blog/development/2014/09/18/angular-js-custom-filters-separate-modules).

--Edit

As [n00dl3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141306/939634) mentions below the tricky part is how the auto-naming convention works in Angular. If you name your filter `specialNumberFilter` then when you inject it you need to refer to it as *`specialNumberFilterFilter`*. This allows you to use the filter as a function, which is what it is.

`// In a controller
vm.data = specialNumberFilterFilter(vm.data, 'a');`

But I believe you can also use the filter without injecting it into a controller if it is used in a string expression that is being evaluated by, say, a watch because this would be the same as the scenario when you are using it in a template.

`` // Inside a watch - no controller injection required
`$scope.$watch('vm.data | specialNumberFilter', function(new, old) { ... })` ``

Comment: Actually, it's not enough, according to angular's documentation, **you do need to inject the filter if you want to use it in your controller**, you should inject it like this:
`controller('MyController', ['<filter name>Filter', function(<filter name>Filter) {}]);` [RTFM](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#using-filters-in-controllers-services-and-directives)

Comment: Blog link appears to be broken/down.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use filter inside a controller you have to inject `$filter` attribute to your controller and can access it like

```
$filter('filtername');
```

You can use like

```
function myCtrl($scope, $filter)
{
    $filter('filtername')(arg1,arg2);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## According to Angular's documentation :

#### if you want to use your filter in a template

then you just need to inject it in your module and then use it like this `{{ expression | filter }}` or `{{ expression | filter:argument1:argument2:... }}` .

[doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#using-filters-in-view-templates)

#### if you want to use your filter in a controller, directive, and stuffs :

inject a dependency with the name `<filterName>Filter`, like this :

```
controller('MyController', ['filterFilter', function(filterFilter) {}]);
```

[doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#using-filters-in-controllers-services-and-directives)

#### so for this particular case :

```
angular.module('equiclass.controllers')
  .controller('CourseCtrl', function ($scope, testFilterFilter) {

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

you didn't mention if it's in production or on a local server, but just in case you are minifying your files, try this:

```
angular.module('equiclass.controllers')
  .controller('CourseCtrl', ['$scope', 'testFilter', function ($scope, testFilter) {

  }]);
```