# Unknown provider: The Filter was injected correctly, still throws an error

Tags: angularjs

I don't understand whats going on, so I hope you can help me.

### Whats the problem?

I created a filter in my module, injected it (couldn't find any spelling errors or something similar) and the Chrome Console throws ans error: Unkown Provider.

### My Code

```
angular.module('Prizeplay.Lobby.Browser', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('Prizeplay.Lobby.Browser')
    .filter('tournamentFilter', [function() {
        return function(input, filter) {
            console.log('tournamentFilter: Success!');
            return input;
        };
    }])
    .directive('appTournamentBrowser', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: ['$scope', 'tournamentFilter', 'filterService', function($scope, tournamentFilter, filterService) {

                $scope.activeRow = null,

                    $scope.tournaments = [];

                $scope.$on('filter:changed', function(event, currentFilter) {
                    //this works perfectly :)
                    $scope.tournaments = $filter('tournamentFilter')($scope.tournaments, currentFilter);
                    //this does not work :(
                    $scope.tournaments = tournamentFilter($scope.tournaments, currentFilter);
                });

                $scope.setRow = function(id) {
                    $scope.activeRow = id;
                };

            }],
            templateUrl: 'lobby/browser/tournament-browser.tpl.html'
        };
    }]);
```

What did I try?
After 1 hour I gave up searching for any injection errors and asked google. Google showed me [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105315/angularjs-custom-filter-cant-be-injected-unknown-provider) on Stackoverflow. I read BKM's comment and tried it. Well... for some reason it worked.

But using my filters with `$filter` looks wrong to me. Why can't I go the way the Developer Guide showed me?

Comment: I found my mistake. It was the name of the Filter. I had to remove the "Filter" of "tournamentFilter"... just lol.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is very simple.  The injection process is injecting **modules**, not other definition points.  In any example where a filter is injected, they are filters which were defined in a different module.  Anything defined in the current module cannot / should not be injected.

For example, in the [Angular.js phonecat app](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09):

```
angular.module('phonecatFilters', []).filter('checkmark', function() 
....

angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngRoute','phonecatControllers','phonecatFilters'])
```

in order to use this filter, the `phonecatFilters` module is injected, not the `checkmark` filter.

Comment: This is not correct. It is possible to define a filter in the same module in which you are using the filter.

Comment: Oh yeah, makes sense :P Sorry missunderstood it.